# How to parse and get data from Json array inside an Json array?

Tags: android, arrays, json

```
{
"images": [
    [
        2,
        "91/914fbbb8694ba1865b7bf3da0cc7ec512a0630dcf16c3f8347b6b4d3.png",
        760,
        3910
    ],
    [
        1,
        "6c/6c9f754578229fb925cb80033cced89ff3ff56795fc50899d3718725.png",
        760,
        5242
    ],
    [
        0,
        "44/446c0ce1047fd617ee086aaa21277229f21b0d29a753c8e3a0df8ca0.png",
        760,
        1080
    ]
]}
```

** Need to access the data inside each array in Images array...How to get those data into a array list **

Comment: lets say a variable json is that object. You can select 1080 by querying `json.images[2][3]`

Comment: I believe that array of `any` should be avoided though, the first element is number while the second element is a string, and then the third and fourth element is number. No type consistency there.

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
 JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject("response");
 JSONArray myArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("images");;

 for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length(); j++) {
    try {
          JSONArray jsonarray = myArray.optJSONArray(j);
          for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++){
              String data = jsonarray.getString(j);
              Log.e("PHOTOS_URL", i + "=" + data);
              arrayList.add(data);
           }

         } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you will try it out :)

Comment: @Nilesh response is in JSonObject then how can you parse it yo jsonarray??

Comment: @ShashwatGupta my mistake just chech updated ans i was just updating my ans please check it

Comment: still your answer is not appropriate, Still you are making instance of jsonArray with response when response is in jsonObject

Comment: you can not put jsonObject into jsonArray bro..., it will give you class castexception

Comment: check it now @ShashwatGupta and please also remove down vote thank you for your suggestion

Comment: now its good, i am suggesting you always try to use optJSONArray() instead of getJSONArray() cause it may lead to crash if there is no data where opt is role liek handler

Comment: @Santhosh check updated ans bro

Comment: @ShashwatGupta This one is working thanks but in the arrayList when data is added its been added 4 times same data

Comment: @Santhosh check updated ans borther

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have jsonResponse is response

then `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responce);`

then `JSONArray imagejsonArray=jsonObject.optJSONArray("images");`

then:

```
for(int i = 0; i < imagejsonArray.length(); i++){
JSONArray jsonarray=imagejsonArray.optJSONArray(i);

}
```

now the object json array are your last jsonarray parsed