# getJSONArray inside another json array

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have the following JSON struncture:

```
{  
   "schedule":{
      "day":[
         {  
            "id":"Monday",
            "items":[
                {
                },
                {
                }
            ]
         }, 
         {  
            "id":"Tuesday",
            "items":[
                {
                },
                {
                }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And what I basically want to do is reach the **items** array inside the **day** array which is inside the **schedule** object.

But whenever I try to get the second JSON array, I get **getJSONArray
(int) in JSONArray cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)**.

```
JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(dayJSON);
JSONArray dayArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("schedule").getJSONArray("day").getJSONArray("items");
```

Comment: Hint : you have to use for loops.

Comment: try to separate the getters of the Json getJsonArray and getJsonObject to seperate lines and i am sure you will find the problem.

it basically says you are trying to fetch a String into Array

Comment: @Ibrahim **for (int i = 0; i < dayArray.length(); i++) {**...and so on...riiight

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse and get data from Json array inside an Json array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195204/how-to-parse-and-get-data-from-json-array-inside-an-json-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Two **`for loop`** respect to **`JSONArray`**.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(success);
JSONObject JOBJ_Schedule = obj.getJSONObject("schedule");
JSONArray schedule_Array = JOBJ_Schedule.getJSONArray("day");

    for (int i = 0; i < schedule_Array.length(); i++) 
    {
    JSONObject jOBJ = schedule_Array.getJSONObject(i);

           JSONArray jArray = jOBJ.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int j = 0; j < jArray.length(); j++) 
            {
                JSONObject jOBJNEW = jArray.getJSONObject(j);

            }


    }
```

Comment: This kinda solved my issue, the only thing is that it repeats all strings inside **items** 4 times.

Comment: @Alin glad to hear .FYI Debug please .Sloppy mistake coming .

Comment: Found id :D The issus was here: JSONObject jOBJNEW = jArray.getJSONObject(**j**); You wrote an **i** instead of **j** and it was pretty darn hard to find :))

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `day` is a list of objects. So basically, you'd have to do something like `getJSONArray("day").get(0).getJSONArray("items")`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
try {
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject("dayJSON");
            JSONObject schedule= baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("schedule");
            JSONArray day=schedule.optJSONArray("day");

            for (int i=0; i<day.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject data = day.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = data.getString("id");

                JSONArray items = data.getJSONArray("items");
                for (int j = 0; j < items.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject data2 = day.getJSONObject(i);
                    String str = data2.getString("YOurkey");
                    Log.e("categories", str);
                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the JSON you provided, `baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("schedule").getJSONArray("day")` will return you a JSONArray instead of JSONObject. 
There is a "item" JSONArray inside each "day" JSONObject. < May be this is the reason.

You can try

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("schedule").getJSONArray("day").length() ; i++){
       JSONArray itemArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("schedule").getJSONArray("day")
                 .getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("items");
}
```