# How to parse this type of json array in android?

Tags: android, android-json

I have know to parser JSON array in single array but how to pass multiple JSON array and set it value to require
[image]

```
 {"scode":"200","all_menu":[{"app_menu_id":"67","app_menu_name":"Demograpics","all_sub_menu":[{"app_menu_id":"67","app_sub_menu_id":"47","app_sub_menu_name":"\u0a97\u0ac1\u0a9c\u0ab0\u0abe\u0aa4\u0ac0","app_sub_menu_image":"http:\/\/app.hindipublic.com\/app_allwhatsupstatus\/menu\/medium\/8451504072003.jpg"}],"sub_menu":"true"},{"app_menu_id":"68","app_menu_name":"Lyrics","all_sub_menu":[{"app_menu_id":"68","app_sub_menu_id":"48","app_sub_menu_name":"Music","app_sub_menu_image":"http:\/\/app.hindipublic.com\/app_allwhatsupstatus\/menu\/medium\/4681504072092.jpg"}],"sub_menu":"true"},{"app_menu_id":"69","app_menu_name":"Adult","all_sub_menu":[{"app_menu_id":"69","app_sub_menu_id":"49","app_sub_menu_name":"Double
 Meaning","app_sub_menu_image":"http:\/\/app.hindipublic.com\/app_allwhatsupstatus\/menu\/medium\/9931504072151.jpg"}],"sub_menu":"true"},{"app_menu_id":"70","app_menu_name":"Emotions","all_sub_menu":[{"app_menu_id":"70","app_sub_menu_id":"50","app_sub_menu_name":"Love","app_sub_menu_image":"http:\/\/app.hindipublic.com\/app_allwhatsupstatus\/menu\/medium\/7611504072164.jpg"}],"sub_menu":"true"},{"app_menu_id":"71","app_menu_name":"Wishes","all_sub_menu":[{"app_menu_id":"71","app_sub_menu_id":"51","app_sub_menu_name":"Good
 Morning","app_sub_menu_image":"http:\/\/app.hindipublic.com\/app_allwhatsupstatus\/menu\/medium\/5171504072183.jpg"}],"sub_menu":"true"},{"app_menu_id":"72","app_menu_name":"Among Friend","all_sub_menu":[{"app_menu_id":"72","app_sub_menu_id":"52","app_sub_menu_name":"Friendship","app_sub_menu_image":"http:\/\/app.hindipublic.com\/app_allwhatsupstatus\/menu\/medium\/4411504072205.jpg"}],"sub_menu":"true"},{"app_menu_id":"73","app_menu_name":"Jokes","all_sub_menu":[{"app_menu_id":"73","app_sub_menu_id":"53","app_sub_menu_name":"Santa
 Banta","app_sub_menu_image":"http:\/\/app.hindipublic.com\/app_allwhatsupstatus\/menu\/medium\/4331504072225.jpg"}],"sub_menu":"true"},{"app_menu_id":"74","app_menu_name":"Featured","all_sub_menu":[{"app_menu_id":"74","app_sub_menu_id":"54","app_sub_menu_name":"Ganpati
 Bappa","app_sub_menu_image":"http:\/\/app.hindipublic.com\/app_allwhatsupstatus\/menu\/medium\/4771504072247.jpg"}],"sub_menu":"true"}]}
```

Comment: show your work please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46195340/7230266 refer this answer

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: You must try it by yourself first.If you meet the problem ,you can show it here.

Comment: Ok, show your code, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse and get data from Json array inside an Json array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195204/how-to-parse-and-get-data-from-json-array-inside-an-json-array)

Comment: you have to use nested for loop to parse this type of JSON

Comment: i edited my question and upload image to require output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("JSONResponse");

    String scode = jsonObject.optString("scode");
    JSONArray allmenuArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("all_menu");

    for (int i = 0; i < allmenuArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject objectJson = allmenuArray.optJSONObject(i);
        boolean sub_menu = objectJson.getBoolean("sub_menu");
        String app_menu_id = objectJson.getString("app_menu_id");
        String app_menu_name = objectJson.getString("app_menu_name");
        JSONArray all_sub_menu = objectJson.getJSONArray("all_sub_menu");

        for (int j = 0; j < all_sub_menu.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject data = allmenuArray.optJSONObject(j);
            Log.e("app_menu_id", data.getString("app_menu_id"));
            Log.e("app_sub_menu_id", data.getString("app_sub_menu_id"));
            Log.e("app_sub_menu_name", data.getString("app_sub_menu_name"));
            Log.e("app_sub_menu_image", data.getString("app_sub_menu_image"));
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("ERROr", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: sub array parser how to set value in uploaded image format

Comment: get sub array data value in your variable

Answer (score 1):

Suppose "response" is your JSONResponse

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);// This is used to get jsonObject from response

String sCode=jsonObject.optString("scode"); // This is how you can parse string from jsonObject
JSONArray allmenuArray=jsonObject.optJSONArray("all_menu"); //This is how you can parse JsonArray from jsonObject
for(int i=0;i<allmenuArray.length();i++){
JSONObject objectJson=allmenuArray.optJSONObject(i);//This is how you can parse jsonObject from jsonArray
}
```

Like This you can parse all your jsonObject and jsonarray. Just follow these steps you can easily parse your full JSONResponse

Comment: i edited my question and upload image to require output